# Java Animation of a circle

Tags: java, animation

```
public class circleGame extends JApplet{
private boolean animationDone;
private ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

public void init(){
    createCircles(10);

    new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(!animationDone){
                updateAnimation();
                repaint();
                delayAnimation();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void createCircles(int amount){
    for(int i=0; i<amount; ++i){
        circles.add(new Circle());
    }
}

public void delayAnimation(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateAnimation(){
    for(Circle circle: circles){
        circle.x+= circle.deltaX/20.0;
        circle.y+= circle.deltaY/20.0;
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    for(Circle circle: circles){
        g2d.setColor(circle.color);
        int xPosition = (int) (circle.x-circle.radius);
        int yPosition = (int) (circle.y-circle.radius);
        int diameter = circle.radius*2;

        g2d.fillOval(xPosition, yPosition,
                   diameter, diameter);

    }
}
```

I am trying to create a given amount of circles and enable them to animate without any drag or trailing of color as is with the current code. The circles should move fluidly across the JApplet without dragging color

Comment: What is the proper way according to you..?

Comment: I don't know if I asked the question right, or let me rephrase it then... What is a way that works to animate circles so they don't drag their color. Right now the code works for circles to drag across the screen and not just the circles themselves, erasing the path as it animates.

Comment: Do you want to drag the circles and leave all the previous circles drawn? Is that it? Or is it the opposite? Your explanation is rather confusing.

Comment: I want a circle to animate without leaving a trail, not sure how to make that any more clear. So it's the circle with it's original radius, but it moves across the JApplet. No dragging of the circles I want them to drag nothing but just fluid movement on every circle created.

Comment: While issue revolves around your abuse of the paint mechanism, I would avoid updating the positions of the circles in any paint methods (or the EDT) for that matter, instead update them in your thread before or after the sleep

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do this would be to clear everything that was drawn before by adding

```
g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

at the beginning of your `paint` method. However, I would rather recommend using a dedicated `JComponent` for drawing the circles and overriding it's `paintComponent` method instead of `paint`. This will take care of this for you, and also prevent the applet from flickering.

```
class CirclesComponent extends JComponent {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // insert content of your paint method here
    }
}
```

Add this to your applet by adding `this.getContentPane().add(new CirclesComponent());` at the beginning of your `init` method and remove the original `paint` method.

Comment: Presumably you mean `super.paintComponent()` without the last "s".